# Spring form doesn't submit to database correctly

Tags: java, spring, forms, jsp, jpa

I have a form where a user fills everything out in a settings page. All of it works except two fields. I'm not sure if it's the form or Controller or my table set up.

Here are the forms that aren't working.

```
<form:input path="minimumCost" type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputAmount" placeholder=""></form:input>
```

and

```
<form:input path="rate" type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputAmount" placeholder=""></form:input>
```

but this one DOES work

```
<form:input path="houseSize" type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputAmount" placeholder=""></form:input>
```

Here is the JPA i configured with them

```
@Column(name = "minimum_Cost")
private String minimumCost;

@Column(name = "rate")
private String rate;

@Column(name = "house_size")
private String houseSize;

public String getMinimumCost() {
    return minimumCost;
}

public void setMinimumCost(String minimumCost) {
    this.minimumCost = minimumCost;
}

public String getRate() {
    return rate;
}

public void setRate(String rate) {
    this.rate = rate;
}

public String getHouseSize() {
    return houseSize;
}

public void setHouseSize(String houseSize) {
    this.houseSize = houseSize;
}
```

Why are the minimumCost and rate showing up as null and houseSize works? They're all in the same form so it's not like they're being left out.

Comment: Why are you using the same `id` for all inputs?

Comment: Not really my HTML code, but is that the problem?

Comment: @bmarkham : How are you taking these values inside controller? Can you show me a method signature? like void methodA(@ModelAttribute User user, ...) or thru httpservletrequest.getparameter? In the end what I want to do is, the controller method which processes these form values, can you try to print out those 3 values inside that controller method?

Comment: @FarazDurrani I found out that the source of the problem is html structure. I haven't been trying to solve it recently

Comment: oh okay I also started with spring mvc 5 months ago. Your question looked simple enough for me to try to help xD

Comment: @FarazDurrani Oh no worries! Thanks for trying anyways.

Answer (score 0):

remove id="exampleInputAmount"   and try it again~

Comment: still have the same problem :/